# Employer wants to add my LinkedIn URL to my Business Card. Should I object?

Tags: linkedin, business-cards

I'm a professional developer for a consulting company.  I don't go onsite with clients often, but it does happen (so I don't use business cards often, but I have them).  My employer is in the process of replacing all business cards (new head office address), and has asked that we provide our LinkedIn URLs to appear on our cards.

Should I care/object?  I tend to have a high degree of concern about privacy, and this request bothers me, but I can't really articulate why (which makes me suspect I'm overreacting).  I'm not looking to change jobs, I like where I work, etc.  I guess I feel that my LinkedIn presence is a personal resource and not a corporate resource.  On the other hand, the only likely outcome is additional professional connections on LinkedIn, which is probably a net positive should I ever want to consider other opportunities.

**Edit to clarify:** I do recognize that LinkedIn is not a private resource in the way that, say, a Facebook page is (although it does allow privacy controls).  What I meant to say is that I view my LinkedIn page as a personal resource for making professional connections, not as my employer's resource for marketing, and that my general concerns about online privacy make me tend to be concerned anytime I feel like a line is being blurred.

Comment: Why do you think Linkedln is personal resources? If you want privacy, do it on Facebook.

Comment: I think you might have answered your own question? Only you can say whether you object, but as you've just said there shouldn't be a downside.

Comment: You put up a LinkedIn to be seen.  Whatever's private shouldn't be there.

Comment: Apart from it being otherwise easy to find, it's much like putting your email address or phone number on the business card - only you can decide whether you want people who you give the card to to use it to reach out to you (we can't make that decision for you). If you want to know **how** to object, or how your employer might respond to you objecting, then we can probably help.

Comment: @SmallChess and WesleyLong - Your comments show I didn't state my concerns well; I've added a clarification about "Privacy".  Thanks!

Comment: So why not make a seperate Linked In profile that is specifically for this businesses purposes?

Comment: @Dukeling I'm not as concerned about communicating my concerns, I'm just looking for other opinions on whether or not this seems to be an inappropriate request or if I'm not viewing it in the right light.  Please add your comment as an answer, I think it's worth an upvote.

Comment: @JasonClark "only you can decide" is more a comment on the appropriateness of the question than an answer.

Comment: What would your employer do if you didn't have a LinkedIn account? Force you to get one?

Comment: There's nothing to stop one changing their LinkedIn url after the cards are printed if it really bothers you!

Comment: That is your personal account and you can object to include it on your business card. It's not overreacting. I too would feel uncomfortable with it. You could simply say that this information belongs to you and that if the company requires a similar profile, that you can maintain another one under your company's email address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I object?

**No**, you should not object.  LinkedIn was made precisely for this type of use.  I cannot think of anything private that you should *ever have on LinkedIn*.

In this case the marketing aspect works both ways.  If visits are obtained via your employers business cards, you are still getting visibility which is almost always a bonus on LinkedIn.  ( The more marketable you are the more you typically get paid )

Comment: Down-voter please explain so I can improve my answer.

Comment: +1 to this. I'd also add that you (the OP) are one of the products your company is selling. Allowing prospective clients to browse your linkedin is a way of showing off the your history and education, hopefully resulting in more interest in your company's services.

Answer (score 1):

Your LinkedIn account is *your* account. Unlike a business number of work email it isn't something provided by your employer. So you are right; it's something which belongs to you and the decision to put it on your business card would, in an ideal world, be up to you.

However, what your employer has done is (I think) a misdemeanor level offense since, theoretically, the information available through LinkedIn probably isn't super-personal in nature and is probably related to your job.

It wouldn't be out of line to simply and casually ask your employer if there's anyway your LinkedIn URL can be left off your card, but expect them to say 'no' and roll with it. There are lots of aggravating things in the world that we can't control, your business card is (most likely) about to become just one more.